# Error in Access INSERT INTO statement from VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledb

```
Private Sub submit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles submit.Click
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim dbProvider As String = "PROVIDER = Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;"
    Dim dbSource As String = "DATA SOURCE =" & Application.StartupPath & "\hospital.mdb"
    con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
    If Not con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        con.Open()
    End If
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO userdata(masterid, pname, aname, dob, bloodgroup, address, gender, referto, designation, relh, mpass, ward, bed, zone)" & _
    "VALUES ('" & Me.masterid.Text & "','" & Me.pname.Text & "','" & Me.aname.Text & "','" & Me.dob.Text & "','" & Me.bloodgroup.Text & "','" & _
    Me.address.Text & "','" & Me.gender.Text & "','" & Me.referto.Text & "','" & Me.designation.Text & "','" & Me.relh.Text & "','" & Me.mpass.Text & "','" & _
    Me.ward.Text & "','" & Me.bed.Text & "','" & Me.zone.Text & "')"
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    con.Close()
End Sub
```

And the values going in the cmd.Commandtext is

```
"INSERT INTO userdata(masterid, pname, aname, [dob], bloodgroup, address, gender, referto, designation, relh, mpass, ward, bed, zone)VALUES ('305201323114','fsdfsd','sdfsd','5/29/2013','AB+','sdfsd','Male','sdfsd','sdfsd','sdfsd','sdfdsf','sdfsdf','dfds','North East Zone')"
```

Comment: And the error you're getting is? It makes it much easier for us to solve a problem if, after you say "I get an error" you immediately say "The error is " and provide a description of the error, including the *exact text* of any error message you get. You have the information right in front of you. Why not share it to make it easier on the people you're asking to help you for free so they don't have to work as hard to provide it?

Comment: This code will be vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

One potential problem with the SQL statement you generated is `'5/29/2013'`. Jet normally uses hash marks `#` (not single quotes `'`) as date delimiters so you may be getting a "Type mismatch" error by trying to assign a string to a Date/Time field.

In any case, you can avoid these kinds of problems (and others, like SQL Injection) by using a *parameterized query*. It would go something like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO userdata (masterid, pname, aname, dob, bloodgroup, address, gender, referto, designation, relh, mpass, ward, bed, zone) " & _
    "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Me.masterid.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Me.pname.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Me.aname.Text)
' [... and so on ...]
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Me.zone.Text)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Do yourself a favour and start using this method instead of "gluing together" long strings of troublesome (and vulnerable!) SQL code.